# Why Load/Store from buffer takes one whole clock cycle?

Tags: caching, assembly, parallel-processing, cpu, clock

In this video: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/click-crash-course-modern-hardware

At 28:00, he starts to explain the following example:

```
ld rax <- [rbx+16]   //Clock 0 Starts
add rbx,16
cmp rax,0
jeq null_chk
st [rbx-16] <- rcx   //Clock 1 Starts
ld rcx <- [rdx+0]    //Clock 2 Starts. Why clock 1 only does one op?
ld rax <- [rax+8]    //Clock 3 Starts. Why?
```

And at 29:48, he says 2 cache misses happen in the example. Why 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, he says that there are 2 cache misses `running in parallel`.
Out of the 4 memory accesses here (data memory, but let's ignore code/page walks, etc):

1. First ld of address `[rbx+16]` can be dispatched and sent to memory.
2. The store can not be performed until retirement when it's known to be non-bogus for sure (he mentioned the branch possibly being mis-predicted - that can be known at execution time, which is before retirement, but there could be other cases he didn't mention, like faults or exceptions). In addition, the store address needs to wait for the calculation of `add rbx, 16`, but that shouldn't take too long. However, the execution and eventually retirement of the branch that's holding the store depends on the result of the `rax` compare & jmp, which in turn depends on the first load - assumed here to go to memory (in other words - don't hold your breath).
3. The 2nd load (from `[rdx+0]`) is independent and can be dispatched - that's the 2nd load done in parallel.
4. The 3rd load can't be dispatched - its address depends on `rax`, which just like the cmp+jmp has to wait for the first load to finish. This means we can't do anything with this load, we don't even know the actual address. Think for e.g. what happens in HW if the load return, writes to `rax`, and it turns out that `[rax+8]` equals `[rbx-16]`? You'll have to forward the data from the store.

So, when executing the code, we can right away (withing 1-2 cycles, depends on the decode and address calculation time) send 2 loads - sections #1 and #3. The other memory operations will have to wait. The crucial element for performance here is to launch  your loads as early as possible, and in parallel whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of cache misses! One last question, why clock 1,2,and 3 only have one operation and clock 0 has 4?

Comment: It's oversimplifying a bit, but say every instruction can be decoded and "started" (basically - allocated into the OOO execution engine) in 1 cycle (not including memory latency of course) - he's assuming that the machine can do this to 4 instructions in parallel (look up [superscalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar), but there's another limitation - no more than one load/store instruction per cycle, so the last 3 have to be performed one after the other. It's still negligible compared to the memory latency here. Real CPUs are often riddled with such small limitations.